# Fatal error: Class 'X' not found using spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl

what am trying to do is making an autoloader to my `php` library as follow

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    if (file_exists("MyLib/Helpers/{$class}.php"))
        require_once "MyLib/Helpers/{$class}.php";
}
```

it works fine , if am calling it from the `root->(index.php)`, but for e.g I made new `Directory` such as "Admin" , it throw this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'MySQL' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fone\MyLib\MyLib.php on line 33
```

how I supposed to fix this issue , so if `MyLib` in any directory it works and loads fine?

Comment: Why not define it with absolute path: `require_once __DIR__."/MyLib/Helpers/{$class}.php";`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fully define the path, like that :

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/MyLib/Helpers/{$class}.php"))
        require_once __DIR__ . "/MyLib/Helpers/{$class}.php";
}
```

Assuming that the file that contains the spl_autoload_register is located at the adequate level (otherwise, just update the rest of the path accordingly (e.g. `__DIR__ . "/../../etc..."`).